# How to get the selected spinner item to a string?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-spinner

I'm very confused, I can select an item from spinner and display it in a pop up message. I have this,

```
btnSubmitRequest.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            spinnerJobTypes.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinnerJobTypes_ItemSelected);
        }


private void spinnerJobTypes_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

        string toast = string.Format("{0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

How can I get the response from spinnerJobTypes_ItemSelected to a string so that I can submit it into the database?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Jeff.H is right, but you need the answer in C#. So, you have to do something like this (I tried it):

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
 string selectedItem = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```